# Using DuckDB parameters doesn't seem to be working

Tags: duckdb

Here's a query that's working:

```py
    con.execute(
        f"CREATE TABLE log_data AS SELECT * FROM read_json('{input_file}', "
        f"auto_detect=false, "
        f"columns={json.dumps({'id': 'varchar', '@timestamp': 'varchar', '@version': 'varchar', 'message': 'varchar'})})"
    )
```

And this one isn't:

```py
    con.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE log_data AS SELECT * FROM read_json('$input_file', "
        "json_format='auto',"
        "auto_detect=false,"
        f"columns={json.dumps({'id': 'varchar', '@timestamp': 'varchar', '@version': 'varchar', 'message': 'varchar'})})",
        {'input_file': input_file},
    )
```

With the following error:

```py
duckdb.IOException: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "$input_file"
```

I can't figure out the error at all.

Comment: I don't think those single quotes are correct: `read_json($input_file, ...`

Comment: Thank you! This is different than their docs. If you'd like to fill this in as an answer, i'm happy to accept.